# Django: The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to do a check in the database whether a user has filled in the `Payment_receipt` model form while signing up, the next time the user logs in. If the user has not filled in the form at first, he will be redirected to the page named `plan_select`. I tried this view. But it's giving me the error: "**The page isn't redirecting properly**".

```
def homeview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if Payment_receipt.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return redirect('plan_select')
    else:
        return render(request, 'services/home.html')
```

What could have gone wrong?

I want to do the same check with other models in this view under the condition `if request.user.is_authenticated:`. How do i redirect based on the conditions properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your URL patterns, but it looks as if `return redirect('home')` is redirecting to the same view, creating a redirect loop.

Perhaps you want to render the template there instead:

```
def homeview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if Payment_receipt.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return render(request, 'services/home.html')
        else:
            return redirect('plan_select')
    else:
        return render(request, 'services/home.html')
```

You can simplify that slightly to avoid duplicating the `return render()` line:

```
def homeview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if not Payment_receipt.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return redirect('plan_select')
    return render(request, 'services/home.html')
```

Comment: Yes, `return redirect('home')` is redirecting to the same view `homeview`. Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: Thank you, so many resources online just say "clear your cookies" but when you're a developer that's not the case..